# Kickstart for ubuntu works on vm but not on physical machine

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, kickstart

So I have made a ks.cfg file for Ubuntu 14.04 server edition and uploaded it to http://address/of/my/ks.cfg and modified isolinux/txt.cfg with necessary changes.

Now when I use this ISO on virtual-box it works, but not on the physial machine.
BTW I am installing on physical machine from a usb drive.

Any advice with this issue will be much helpful ..